# Issue with l10n update

Tags: language

On Civicrm 5.13.4 on Drupal 7.67 I have this error when accessing to the Localization page:

> ```
> Notice : Undefined index: addLanguage dans l10nupdate_civicrm_buildForm() (ligne 53 dans /sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/com.cividesk.l10n.update-master/l10nupdate.php).
> Notice : Undefined index: lcMessages dans l10nupdate_civicrm_buildForm() (ligne 53 dans /sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/com.cividesk.l10n.update-master/l10nupdate.php).
> ```

How should I fix this? (.php is not my best)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have submitted a [PR](https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.l10n.update/pull/5) to fix the notice error. Can you try applying the patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/cividesk/com.cividesk.l10n.update/pull/5.patch)?

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: thanks Pradeep, your patch solved this issue!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the error is originating from the `com.cividesk.l10n.update` extension enabled on your site.

- update that extension to latest and check if it fixes the problem for you.
- disable if it is no longer useful.
- Open an issue under https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.l10n.update/issues providing the steps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks jitendra. unfortunately there is no update available since a while.